# Javascript not doing anything - chrome extension

Tags: javascript

I am trying to follow this tutorial to build a very simple first chrome extension.

[Link to tutorial I have been following](https://www.sitepoint.com/create-chrome-extension-10-minutes-flat/)

I have copy and pasted all the exact same code. However, the javascript doesn't seem to be doing anything. When I click on the extension, the popup html code loads right and this comes up.

[What comes up when I click on my extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FILs8.png)

However, when I click on the button that is supposed to engage the javascript, nothing happens. 
I am sure I copied the code exactly, so what is wrong?

Is something missing in the tutorial?

Comment: That was written in 2015... perhaps something changed since then?

Comment: Ok that could be the issue.

Comment: But still, just trying to gain an understanding of javascript, do you see anything wrong/outdated with the code in the tutorial that might be the reason that my JS is not working?

Comment: so, you want me to go through the tutorial and figure out why it's not working?